# Magento 2 Order Email With This Content =0D=0A=0D=0A=0D=0A =0D=0A

Tags: magento2, order-email, magento2.3.3, email-attachment

When order confirmation send all content contain this

> =0D=0A=0D=0A=0D=0A =0D=0A

Here is email screenshot:

[image]

> app\Vendor\Extension\etc\di.xml

```
<preference for="\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilder" type="Vendor\Extension\Model\Template\SenderBuilder"/>
```

> Here is Vendor\Extension\Model\Template\SenderBuilder\send.php
>
> Here is my send function for PDF attache

```
public function send()
    {
        $objectManager = ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $configHelper = $objectManager->get(Data::class);
        if ($configHelper->versionCompare("2.3")) {
            # attach pdf, overide send function
            $attachPdf = $this->attachPDF();
            $this->configureEmailTemplate();
            $this->transportBuilder->addTo(
                $this->identityContainer->getCustomerEmail(),
                $this->identityContainer->getCustomerName()
            );
            $copyTo = $this->identityContainer->getEmailCopyTo();
            if (!empty($copyTo) && $this->identityContainer->getCopyMethod() == 'bcc') {
                foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
                    $this->transportBuilder->addBcc($email);
                }
            }

            #transport email
            $transport = $this->transportBuilder->getTransport();
            $html = $transport->getMessage();
            $message = Message::fromString($html->getRawMessage());
            $bodyMessage = new \Zend\Mime\Part($message->getBody());
            $bodyMessage->type = 'text/html';
            $bodyMessage->charset = 'utf-8';
            $bodyPart = new \Zend\Mime\Message();
            $bodyPart->setParts([$bodyMessage, $attachPdf]);

            #transport email with body part
            $transport->getMessage()->setBodyHtml($bodyPart);
            $transport->sendMessage();
        } else {
            $this->attachPDF();
            parent::send();
        }
    }
```

Comment: can share code by which you are sending mail?

Comment: @chirag please share your code, its looks like the headers are changed, please check the header information, and check the encoding type. From the screen shot I can say the encoding is change. =0D is a Carriage Return (CR), =0A is a Line Feed (LF), and =0D=0A is a CRLF combination displays when encoding or any external event happen which cause the change. Please share your code for more debugging

Comment: Hello, @AshishRanade Here add code please check it.

Answer (score 1):

removing these lines in lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Mail/Message.php

```
  $part->setEncoding(Mime::ENCODING_QUOTEDPRINTABLE); $part->setDisposition(Mime::DISPOSITION_INLINE);
```

Other thing is set encoding of message properly.
See this method at

**vendor\zendframework\zend-mime\src\Mime.php**

```
public static function encode($str, $encoding, $EOL = self::LINEEND)
{
    switch ($encoding) {
        case self::ENCODING_BASE64:
            return static::encodeBase64($str, self::LINELENGTH, $EOL);

        case self::ENCODING_QUOTEDPRINTABLE:
            return static::encodeQuotedPrintable($str, self::LINELENGTH, $EOL);

        default:
            /**
             * @todo 7Bit and 8Bit is currently handled the same way.
             */
            return $str;
    }
}
```

If your email part message is encoded **'quoted-printable'** than it will call encodeQuotedPrintable method which ultimately call private method  **_encodeQuotedPrintable** where line 
**$str = str_replace(static::$qpKeys, static::$qpReplaceValues, $str);** replaced those =0D=0A=0D=0A=0D=0A =0D=0A type of strings.

```
private static function _encodeQuotedPrintable($str)
{
    // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
    $str = str_replace('=', '=3D', $str);
    $str = str_replace(static::$qpKeys, static::$qpReplaceValues, $str);
    $str = rtrim($str);
    return $str;
}
```

Where **$qpReplaceValues**  variable values are below. which are current string in your email part.

```
 public static $qpReplaceValues = [
    "=00","=01","=02","=03","=04","=05","=06","=07",
    "=08","=09","=0A","=0B","=0C","=0D","=0E","=0F",
    "=10","=11","=12","=13","=14","=15","=16","=17",
    "=18","=19","=1A","=1B","=1C","=1D","=1E","=1F",
    "=7F","=80","=81","=82","=83","=84","=85","=86",
    "=87","=88","=89","=8A","=8B","=8C","=8D","=8E",
    "=8F","=90","=91","=92","=93","=94","=95","=96",
    "=97","=98","=99","=9A","=9B","=9C","=9D","=9E",
    "=9F","=A0","=A1","=A2","=A3","=A4","=A5","=A6",
    "=A7","=A8","=A9","=AA","=AB","=AC","=AD","=AE",
    "=AF","=B0","=B1","=B2","=B3","=B4","=B5","=B6",
    "=B7","=B8","=B9","=BA","=BB","=BC","=BD","=BE",
    "=BF","=C0","=C1","=C2","=C3","=C4","=C5","=C6",
    "=C7","=C8","=C9","=CA","=CB","=CC","=CD","=CE",
    "=CF","=D0","=D1","=D2","=D3","=D4","=D5","=D6",
    "=D7","=D8","=D9","=DA","=DB","=DC","=DD","=DE",
    "=DF","=E0","=E1","=E2","=E3","=E4","=E5","=E6",
    "=E7","=E8","=E9","=EA","=EB","=EC","=ED","=EE",
    "=EF","=F0","=F1","=F2","=F3","=F4","=F5","=F6",
    "=F7","=F8","=F9","=FA","=FB","=FC","=FD","=FE",
    "=FF"
];
```

Comment: We not found this file  lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Mail/Message.php

Comment: @ChiragGondaliya Check updated answer. It will help you to understand the problem.

Comment: Now what to do in my code for solution for this issue.

Comment: @ChiragGondaliya Set encoding and set disposition
setEncoding('base64') and setDisposition('inline')
and if that also does not solve than setEncoding('quoted-printable') and setDisposition('inline')

Comment: I try set encoding and disposition but not work.

Comment: what if you remove your own code and set magento's default code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102007/discussion-between-padhiyar-gaurang-and-chirag-gondaliya).

Comment: @PadhiyarGaurang, commenting out **$part->setEncoding(Mime::ENCODING_QUOTEDPRINTABLE);** is sufficient. It worked for me with this line commented only.